# Add Service Reference into React Native project?

Tags: c#, react-native, service-reference

May i know is there a way to add c# service reference into a react native project?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found another solution that writing a SOAP function in a node.js. You can simply run `npm install soap` in your node.js and follow the [soap documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap) and it works like charm. This method can save a lot of time compare with the C# Web Service method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I added a new Web API layer to communicate with the service reference. Seems like that is only way to communicate with service reference.